# Extract methods with return statements

Tags: c#, return, refactoring

I am trying to refactor some code by extracting methods. I need to separate the (simplified) code below into sub methods for each region, but I get the error "*When the selection contains a return statement, all code paths must be terminated by a return statement too*".

```
try
        {
            #region one
            if (order == "1")
            {
                ...do something
                return result;
            }
            #endregion

            #region two
            if (order == "2")
            {
                ...do something
                return result;
            }
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...exception handle
        }
        return result;
```

How should this be done?

Comment: What gives you this error? At which place?

Comment: When I use built in VS functionality to extract a region into a sub method @Sinatr

Comment: Never did that, my guess it has some limitations, you can check [info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s21cwxk.aspx) about that function or .. just do it manually.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem. I think that this is by design because extracting a method in this context (the region block) would create invalid code

Comment: This is the first I have come across this error so wasn't quite sure. I can try manually extracting the method to avoid the problem. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the *body* of each `if` statement into its own method.  You cannot extract the entire `if` statement into a method, for exactly the reason the error message you're getting is telling you.

Comment: Thank you for the help here Servy. This seems to work, both using VS functionality and doing it manually, whereas before suggestion broke the logic